# eBay full purchase history

Tags: web-apps, chrome, firefox, history, ebay

eBay erase details of purchase history after a year, supposedly because it takes too much disk space (I suspect they just don't want people to see how much they spend over the years).

Is there a tool that could capture my history and make it easy to see details even years in the future?

It could be a browser add-on, a web service using eBay's API or scraping, or something else.

Requirements:

- Show all purchased items ever, including:

  - Date
  - Price
  - Full description page of the item
  - Dated delivery steps
- Free
- Any browser, any OS OK
- Bonus if it can capture the information after a purchase even though the purchase was performed on a device on which the tool was not installed

Comment: How about from ebay or (if you use) paypal statements? I think you can go back a couple of years, and both have .csv download so you can manipulate the data however you want. I don't see how you can get data older than what they make available, though.

Comment: @user3169: Payment statement contain some level of information indeed but not enough.

Comment: @user3169: Explanation scenario: I start using SuperEBayPurchaseHistoryTool in 2016. It will not enable me to see my 1999 purchases. But if I keep using it, in 2032 I will still be able to see my 2017 purchases.